# How to avoid DevExpress Spreadsheet freeze while doing heavy calculations?

Tags: c#, devexpress, backgroundworker, spreadsheet

I use DevExpress Spreadsheet in my own project. I created a button in the ribbon for doing some calculation over cells. It gets information from cells of a sheet and creates a new sheet and calculation results are written into its rows and cells. Those calculations are done over more than 5000 rows. The UI freezes for about 10 seconds. I don't want to use progress bar, but I'd use a progress animation comes with DevExpress (it's called progress panel and is like Windows 10 loading dots).
I tried to use BackGroundWorker to avoid UI freeze. Because of cross-thread nature of my operations (creating sheet, writing data in cells ...) I cannot use them directly in DoWork section. So, I use Invoke and Delegation. But my UI and progress animation is still non-responsive during process.

```
       private void barButtonItem5_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
  
    private void FillCell(string _sheetName)
    {
        IWorkbook workbook = spreadsheetControl.Document;
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["DataSet1"];
        CellRange range = worksheet.GetDataRange();
        int LastRow = range.BottomRowIndex;
        var keys = new List<string>();
        var values = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < LastRow + 1; i++)
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[i, 10].DisplayText == "خاتمه یافته")
            {
                keys.Add(string.Join(",", worksheet.Cells[i, 28].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 0].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 9].DisplayText,
                worksheet.Cells[i, 15].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 31].DisplayText));
                values.Add((int)worksheet.Cells[i, 32].Value.NumericValue);
            }
        }
        var mydic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            if (mydic.ContainsKey(keys[i]))
            {
                mydic[keys[i]] += values[i];
            }
            else
            {
                mydic.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in mydic.Keys)
        {
            keys.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in mydic.Values)
        {
            values.Add(item);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mydic.Count; i++)
        {
            string text = keys[i];
            string[] rewrite = text.Split(',');

            workbook.Worksheets[_sheetName].Cells[i, 0].SetValue(rewrite[0]);
            workbook.Worksheets[_sheetName].Cells[i, 1].SetValue(rewrite[1]);
            workbook.Worksheets[_sheetName].Cells[i, 2].SetValue(rewrite[2]);
            workbook.Worksheets[_sheetName].Cells[i, 3].SetValue(rewrite[3]);
            workbook.Worksheets[_sheetName].Cells[i, 4].SetValue(rewrite[4]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mydic.Count; i++)
        {
            int text = values[i];

            workbook.Worksheets[_sheetName].Cells[i, 5].SetValue(text);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        
        IWorkbook workbook = spreadsheetControl.Document;
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["DataSet1"];

        if (worksheet.HasData)
        {
            if (spreadsheetBarController1.Control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                //***Instead of (Action), we can use (MethodInvoker)***
                spreadsheetBarController1.Control.Invoke((Action)delegate { CreateSheet("Summarized"); });
                spreadsheetBarController1.Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ClearSheet("Summarized"); });
                spreadsheetBarController1.Control.Invoke((Action)delegate { FillCell("Summarized"); });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("خطای داده ورودی", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressPanel1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressPanel1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of these methods is blocking you? There's too much code. Learn [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions.

Comment: Method FillCell has the most effect on UI freeze. I removed other methods from my question.

Comment: Have you checked async await pattern?

Comment: The reason is that lots of my calculations are related to UI, for example, creating a sheet, clearing a sheet, and filling cell with data. I don't know how to manage them in order to avoid UI freeze.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to use `workbook.BeginUpdate()` at the begin of your `FillCell` method to suppress the `SpreadsheetControl`'s visual updates and improve its performance when you perform multiple changes to a spreadsheet document. Also use `workbook.EndUpdate()` at the end of your `FillCell` method to unlocks the control and enable all the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I used DevExpress.Docs assembly that works very faster than filling the cells manually. My calculated data are put into a DataTable and then are brought to the cells in less than a second.